# Laravel Dropzone Request empty

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, dropzone.js

I'm uploading a single file with Dropzone to a Laravel application.

It's previously worked fine, but has now stopped working.

Dropzone also uploads extra plain text details along with the request. As far as I can tell, the upload is going fine. I can see in Chrome Developer tools that the form fields are there etc (see the request below).

However, if I do a `dd($request->all())` it always returns an empty array.

This is my request as seen through Chrome developer tools:

```
Accept:application/json
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:10939930
Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryzcRfNSSYMQFOU3uH
Cookie:XSRF-TOKEN=SOME_TOKEN_VALUE
Host:gateway
Origin:http://gateway
Referer:http://gateway/tools/videos/create
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.130 Safari/537.36
X-CSRF-Token:TOKEN_VALUE
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest

Request Payload
------WebKitFormBoundaryzcRfNSSYMQFOU3uH
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="video_id"

11
------WebKitFormBoundaryzcRfNSSYMQFOU3uH
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="null"


------WebKitFormBoundaryzcRfNSSYMQFOU3uH
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="SENHS_INTRO.mp4"
Content-Type: video/mp4


------WebKitFormBoundaryzcRfNSSYMQFOU3uH--
```

However, when I `dd($request->all)` it simply returns `[]`.

Even though there is a valid `video_id` request value, and the file `file` has been sent.

Can anyone see anything I have done incorrectly, point to an idea of I might have done so I can try alternate code, or recommend something to do?

If you need extra information, please let me know,

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check `php.ini` and make sure `file_uploads` is set to On and also be sure the `upload_max_filesize` is large enough to handle that file.

Comment: @user3158900 thanks for the reply, I had previously checked these values, but thought after your comment I best double check. `upload_max_filesize` was `2G` and it didn't work on a 10M file, but I had noticed `post_max_size` was 5M. Updating this to the same value as the `upload_max_filesize` value made the upload and request work :) If you want to post it as an answer, I'll accept it. Thanks

Comment: Did u find a way dude ? Same problem